# Session-scoped middleware?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My architecture is such:

> Next.js (browser) -> Next.js (middleware) -> 3rd-party API

The middleware is responsible for storing user's access tokens and such. I'm currently running on local machine and everything runs fine.

Once deployed, is the middleware "session" shared across all sessions or just mine? In other words, if user A authenticates and the middleware retains the access token in an `httpOnly` cookie, then user B authenticates, will user A's accessToken be overwritten, or does the middleware keep track of each user?

Typically, I'm writing my own middleware and deploying functions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Next.js application deployed on a serverless platform, user A's access token in the middleware won't be overwritten by user B's authentication. Each request to your middleware function will have its own isolated context, ensuring data separation between different users.

Don't worry, just go ahead and deploy your application, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: On the login form, there is a checkbox to "remember me." I assume that I'd have to persist the access token locally as the serverless instance will spin down after being idle and will thus lose the context. Am I correct?

Comment: You're right @a11smiles, you need to persist it locally. One very useful package for the same is next-auth: https://next-auth.js.org/. Do let me know in case you need any help implementing this. 